# Spring Integration - How to create the adapters programmatically?

Tags: java, activemq-classic, spring-integration

I am implementing spring-integration based application where i need to send messages (POJO) to ActiveMQ queues dynamically (based on message params). What is the best way to implement this using spring integration concepts ?

E.g., The request message (id:123, processor:ABC) should be sent to ABC.REQUEST queue and response message should be received from ABC.RESPONSE queue. Similarly the request message (id:456, processor:XYZ) should be sent to XYZ.REQUEST queue and response message should be received from XYZ.RESPONSE queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to programmatically create them programmatically, you can use dynamic destinations.

See `request-destination-expression` and `reply-destination-expression` in [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jms.html#d4e9695).

Something like...

```
request-destination-expression="payload.processor + '.REQUEST'"
reply-destination-expression="payload.processor + '.RESPONSE'"
```

...should do it.